# How to insert comma between the numbers in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to locate positions of a particular character within a long string and capture the positions as comma separated string. For example in the example below, I would like to get s3 value as **3, 4, 10** instead of **"3"  "4"  "10"**. Please advice.

```
s1 <- "Hello.World"
s2 <- which(strsplit(s1, '')[[1]]=='l')
s3 <- gsub(" ",", ",as.character(s2))
s3
[1] "3"  "4"  "10"
```

Comment: Just `paste` the vector together using `collapse=", "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
paste(s2, collapse=", ")
```

Or a a convenient wrapper is `toString`

```
toString(s2)
```

Comment: I missed the the collapse part in the paste and was using sep in vain.